# Chrome Refuses to make Ajax Request to same url after request is aborted

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, iis-express

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in chrome as it doesn't happen in IE 10 and it just started recently, but basically when making an AJAX call to a URL and the user refreshes the browser during the request, all requests to the same url will fail after that. Even if I refresh the browser again, the request fails. The only way I could get around it is by adding a timestamp to make every request unique but this seems like a hack. Am I missing something here?

If you have an aborted request, this will never work again:

```
        $.getJSON("realTimeActivity/GetRealTimeData",
            function (result) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        ).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // No error message comes back
        })
```

Yet this works every time:

```
    $.getJSON("realTimeActivity/GetRealTimeData?u=" + (new Date).getTime(),
        function (result) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    ).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // No error message comes back
    })
```

I could just leave it but I'd like to understand why this is and not need this hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of cacheing, and because the URL is the same as it was before, hence why it ignores it.  By appending a timestamp, makes the URL different, and each request goes through.

Another option is setting cache to false (with .ajax()) which interestingly enough, simply appends a timestamp for you.

[.ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

```
$.ajax({
    /* ... */
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: awesome! I seriously spent days on this and posted in multiple forums before trying to append the url. Now I know why the timestamp fixed it!

Comment: Any reason you would want caching on for ajax requests? I'm wondering if disabling it universally will cause problems with standard update panel ajax requests in asp.net.

Comment: I ask because if I use getJSON looks like I have to disable it through the setup for all requests and not just per request like you can with $.ajax.

Comment: You more than likely wouldn't want to make it global, but more of something you shut off on a case-by-case basis. Most times you want it to be cached anyways, if you are getting constantly changing / updated data then of course you'd want it off! (Like in your situation). I just have a quick function that makes it random for me and I append `url + rand()` to shut off the cache.